# Google Chart Tools does not load

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I can't seem to find why my code isn't working. There are no errors in Chrome's console. 
I believe the data is loaded in  correctly and is not the problem. I think I might have made an error in the actual create of the charts. Can anyone fix my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Load the Visualization API and the controls package.
        google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['controls', 'corechart']});

        // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
        google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

        // Declare variable outside of functions.
        var data;


        function initialize() {
            var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0As-rWerCrohAdHc4M2t3T0c5c3UtOWtTUFg5RHc1VlE&usp=sharing');

            query.send(handleQueryResponse);
        }

        function handleQueryResponse(response) {
            if (response.isError()) {
                alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
                return;
            }
            data = response.getDataTable();
            return data;
        }

        function drawDashboard() {

            var scatterRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
                'containerId': 'filter_div',
                'options': {
                    'filterColumnIndex': 2
                }
            });

            var scatterChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                'chartType': 'ScatterChart',
                'containerId': 'scatter_div',
                'options': {
                    'title': '2000 MLB Teams\' Attendance vs. Wins',
                    'hAxis': {title: 'Attendance'},
                    'vAxis': {title: 'Wins'},
                    'legend': 'none'
                },
                'view': {'columns': [5, 6]}

            });

            var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                'chartType': 'Table',
                'containerId': 'table2',
                'options': {
                    'width': '900px'
                }
            });

            var tree = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                'chartType': 'Treemap',
                'containerId': 'treemap_div',
                'options': {
                    'title': 'MLB Attendance Treemap'
                },
                'view': {'columns': [1, 5]}
            });

            var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));
                dashboard.bind(scatterRangeSlider, scatterChart);
                dashboard.draw(data);
        }

        google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize); 
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="dashboard_div">
        <div id="scatter_div" style="width: 1000px; height: 800px;"></div>
        <div id="filter_div"></div>
        <div id="table_div" style="width: 1000px; height: 800px;"></div>
        <div id="treemap_div" style="width: 1000px; height: 800px;"></div>  
    </div>  
</body>
```

Comment: Do you need to define initialize before calling google.setOnLoadCallback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your chart drawing code never gets called - you need to call `drawDashboard` from `handleQueryResponse`, or reorganize your code (as there is no obvious reason why you would need to have multiple distinct functions to accomplish this task).  Once you have done that, though, you have some more fixes to make, as your chosen column to filter on with the NumberRangeFilter is not a numeric column (column 2 is "Division").  Your ScatterChart is plotting "Runs Scored" vs "Runs Allowed", not "Home Game Attendance" vs "Wins" (as the chart title implies it should).  The Table is not bound to the Dashboard, so it won't draw - you must either bind it to one or more controls in the Dashboard, or set its `dataTable` parameter to `data` and call its `#draw` methods to draw it without binding.  Also, your data is not in a suitable format to draw a TreeMap.  If you want to use this data set to draw a TreeMap, you will need to transform the data set into a suitable format.

Here's one example of how you might set this up (not including the TreeMap):

```
function initialize() {
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0As-rWerCrohAdHc4M2t3T0c5c3UtOWtTUFg5RHc1VlE&usp=sharing');

    query.send(function (response) {
        if (response.isError()) {
            alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
            return;
        }
        var data = response.getDataTable();

        var scatterRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
            'containerId': 'filter_div',
            'options': {
                'filterColumnIndex': 4
            }
        });

        var scatterChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            'chartType': 'ScatterChart',
            'containerId': 'scatter_div',
            'options': {
                'title': '2000 MLB Teams\' Attendance vs. Wins',
                'hAxis': {title: 'Attendance'},
                'vAxis': {title: 'Wins'},
                'legend': 'none'
            },
            'view': {'columns': [4, 7]}

        });

        var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            'chartType': 'Table',
            'containerId': 'table2',
            'options': {
                'width': '900px'
            }
        });

        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));
        dashboard.bind([scatterRangeSlider], [scatterChart, table]);
        dashboard.draw(data);
    });
}

google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['controls'], callback: initialize});
```

See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/9mBn6/